# Convert first row header to numeric format after transposing the data

Tags: r, transpose, numeric

[Raw data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po4f2.png)
The column of my data is over the limit of excel(ASV number to be over 20000), so I switch the column and row in R.

```
>PC.T <- t (PC)
>PC.T <- t(PC[,2:ncol(PC)])
>colnames(PC.T) <- PC[,1] .
```

Originally in excel, the first row is supposed to be numeric(sample size), but after transpose in R, they became X1, X2, X3...How can I change the first column into numeric format after transposing it?
[after transposing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzEvj.png)

Comment: That's not the first column, those are the `rownames`.

Comment: anything I can do to include my sample size in the very first column after transposing?

Comment: `PC.T <- cbind.data.frame(rownames(PC.T), PC.T)`.